# Magnetic Force - Point of Load

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, torque, solid-mechanics, magnets

I am using a Magnet like [this](https://www.supermagnete.de/topfmagnete-mit-gewindezapfen/topfmagnet-mit-gewindezapfen-40mm_GTN-40) in an assembly and I am trying to calculate the torque in point P2 (see picture below) resulting from the attraction force F between my magnet and the steel part.

As I assume that the magnetic force is a volumetric one, I am not sure which distance to point P2 to take for my torque calculation.

In the case of an equidistant gap (no tilting) between the rotational symmetric Aluminium part which is carrying the magnet and the Steel part, I think the resulting Force can be seen as it is applied in the center of the magnet which is in a distance of L1 to P2?

[image: Force resulting from magnet without tilting]

Therefore, in this case the resulting torque around P2 would be: M=F*L1.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

But in the case of tilting I am not sure which distance (L2 or LP) to consider for torque calculation.
As P1 is the only contact point between the two parts it might be the point where the load on the steel plate is applied?

This would lead to M_tilt = F*LP.
[image: Force resulting from magnet with tilting]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'd need a pretty special magnet to apply force anywhere close to this uniformly. It will be distributed with location of the poles of the magnet, and in case of your tilt, it varies with inverse *7th power* of distance from the steel.

Comment: @SF I would be very interested if you could point to some introductory reference material I can read so that I can derive the 7th power. Magnetic forces are still a bit of a black box for me. I'm even tempted to put it as a new question!

Comment: @NMech Ask around on Physics.SE I found someone tell me that there and it was enough to completely extinguish my desire to dig deeper - it's not an easy subject,  Normal magnet-magnet interactions tend to vary with square of distance and are a "regular difficulty" subject to study, but inert non-magnetized iron/steel becomes a magnet the stronger the closer to a permanent magnet it gets, that in turn increases the field strength which makes it magnetized even stronger, and the exponent of the distance really explodes, and the mathematics of this becomes really difficult.

Comment: As for practical, real-life applications, probably an experimental / measure approach would be most practical. The magnet's attraction strength will vary with steel composition, thickness (irrespective of mass), magnetic permeability of possible coating and the aluminum casing, and other factors you may not even be aware of, never mind be able to include in calculation.

Comment: wow 1/x^7 , didn't know! Besides that the hysteresis and saturation effects are very pronounced. If OP only needs the location known, and magnitude can vary, then one could potentially concentrate the magnetic field lines with another piece of ferrous metal. 3D structures also exist that shape the field into a relatively uniform one over a selected space - these work well enough that magnetically actuated proportional valves can be reproducible to under 5% (after the hysteresis is eliminated with an AC signal). However this is electromagnet acting on thin steel.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I planned to determine the exact force at different gap distances without tilting. Let's assume the resulting attraction force between the two parts while tilting is at L2, then the torque around P2 is M=LP*F? As the only contact point between two parts is at P1? Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @timosmd I'm feeling like you're wrong but it's currently impossible to tell because we know nothing about possible attachment of the magnet's casing. If the magnet casing is rigidly attached "to background", then P1 counts as the same kind of attachment point as P2 and net torque at P2 is 0 as $F_{L2} \cdot L2 = F_{LP} \cdot LP$. If P1 holds the magnet casing rigidly attached to the plate but not to the "background" then  the magnetic force is moot, and P2 experiences torque counterclockwise from weight of the plate and the magnet.

Comment: Only if P1 is *not* a contact point (magnet attached "to the background" but not in contact with the plate), your torque at P1 will be just the incidence of the $F_{L2}$ and force of gravity (weight of the plate).